# Utilities of states in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: utilities, reinforcement-learning

In Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach (3rd Edition-Russell) book, we have a 4*3 world like this : 
[image]

and with some computation that i didn't understand we reach to this utilities for each states (given R(s)= -0.04 and gamma = 1 for each state) :

[image]

I want to implement this world. Can someone that has read this book (chapter 17) explain for me that how can i compute utilities for each state in this world?

Comment: The utility is the value function (V-function). You might want to read http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/ebook/ or just search for any lecture slide about V-function and Bellman equations. You will find a lot of explained examples.

Comment: There are many ways, but the simplest is to apply the value iteration algorithm (17.2.2) in Russell. You just need to iterate formula (17.6) on every cell. The complete algorithm is shown in Figure 17.4

Comment: @fidelroha Can you able to get answer for this. I am looking for help here. Thanks